# HOw to fix sleep / hibernate issue on MacBook Pro early 2011?

Tags: macbook-pro, startup, sleep-wake

I have a rather old early 2011 MacBook pro that I keep due to ports galore on it. The computer runs generally fine, but I am having issues with wake from sleep/hibernate. I have FileVault turned on.

Normal sleep is fine, computer is on in an instance, but after a while when hibernate kicks in, the computer doesn't seem able to wake from it.

The screen is just black in those occasions, and I need to press and hold power button to force shutdown and then press it again to boot. The computer then boots normally.

It often seems like computer tries to boot, doesn't succeed and then boots again. (I hear two chimes). -  When it works I see no issues from the machine it is fast and reliable. I get 4-5h on battery.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: First thing to check with any machine of that age is if the original hard drive is failing. I'd replace it with an SSD: easy and cheap, and will massively speed things up. A failing or corrupted drive could cause problems booting and retrieving the sleep image from disk.

Comment: SSD in, works fine. - What next?